# Magento 2: Where are the block classes stored?

Tags: blocks

I've enabled **template hints** and **block hints**. I get this template path `/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml` which has this block class `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info`.

Where can I find the code for the block class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the `Info.php` on the below path.

```
/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account/Dashboard/Info.php
```

You can override the block file in your custom module with the help of `preference`. Please visit this [link](https://magenticians.com/magento-2-override-block/) for more information regarding the block overriding.

And `info.phtml` under below path:

```
 /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml
```

You can override this template in your custom theme under the below path:

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml
```

***Hope it helps!!!***

Answer (score 1):

You can check this file's Block here

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account/Dashboard/Info.php

You can override this in your Custom module here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Account/Dashboard/Info.php

Hope this will help you!